# Remapping shortcut buttons on the kinesis freestyle 2

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, remap

This is a niche problem, but making a reference if it helps anyone!

If you have a keyboard with built in shortcut keys and you want to reprogram them, what do you do? I had a kinesis freestyle 2 keyboard (mac and PC versions) that had two rows of built in shortcut keys mapped to a mac, but I wanted to use it on a PC (no way to return for PC dedicated version and printed keys have different shortcuts).

If you go to kinesis' website - a bit user hostile customer service in my experience - they will tell you there is no way to remap the existing buttons... and then they'll happily link you to buying a new $200 keyboard, their "Pro" model, if you want remappable buttons.

Of course there is an easy fix. While there are multiple approaches, I turned to a kind soul with a free utility they've released to make the world a bit better. The utility for Windows is called "SharpKeys" by RandyRants.com and on a Mac, you have a system setting you can change. [Here is a good write up on that](https://www.howtogeek.com/219156/how-to-remap-your-windows-cutcopypaste-to-os-x-like-controls-and-vice-versa/#:%7E:text=It%27s%20no%20different%20with%20modifier,Command%E2%80%9D%20to%20%E2%80%9CControl%E2%80%9D.) by Matt Klein at "howtogeek"

After remapping the control and command keys and purposefully assigning the web back and forward buttons, I then had a useful keyboard... no thanks to Kinesis and their upsell tactic leaving their customers (who paid a premium for their ergonomic keyboard) in the dark with an easy solution in reach..